# Can PageRank run on a non-connected graph?

Tags: graph-algorithm, pagerank

As we know, PageRank should run on the directed graph. But can it run on the non-connected graph like that?[image]

I've tested it and it worked, but I got the wrong PR scores.

The program didn't throw an error to show PageRank shouldn't run on the non-connected graph.

So anyone knows can PageRank run on the non-connected graph?

Thanks a lot！ It means a lot for me.